# How can I concatinate a ng-model value with a value from a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to loop through an array of objects that I receive from a REST service and create a dynamic form using the `ng-repeat` directive.

This is my form with a rating directive (taken for the UI Bootstrap library)

```
<form name="categoryRatingFrom" data-ng-submit="updateCategories(catRatings) >

<div data-ng-repeat="cats in categories" class="form-group clearfix">
  <label class="control-label">{{ cats.name }}</label>
    <div class="no-outline"
          data-rating
          data-ng-model=" // Here I want to concatenate {{ cats.id }} with the ng-model name catRatings // "
          data-max="6"
          data-rating-states="ratingOptions.ratingStates"
          data-on-hover="atmosphereRating.onHover(value)"
          data-on-leave="atmosphereRating.onLeave()"></div>
     </div>
<form>
```

I want to set the `data-ng-model` value using the object name that I pass when submitting and the ID of the current object tin my loop/array, however I don't seem to be able to do this. Should I do the concatenation in the controller on receiving the object array using a loop and then set the data-ng-model using a value from the ng-repeat nothing is passed to the controller when submitting the form (see my code below):

```
// loop through the object adding a ng-model name that we match in our form...
for (var i = 0, l = $scope.categories.length; i < l; i++) {
  $scope.categories[i]['modelId'] = 'catRatings.' + $scope.categories[i].id;
}
```

I add the following to my HTML `data-ng-model="cats.modelId"` but nothing is passed to the controller when submitting - can any one help me with a solution or give me an answer to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `data-ng-model="{{cats.modelId}}"`?

Answer (score 0):

ng-model takes a variable, not a string value. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do but I would think it would be something like:

```
ng-model="catRatings[cats.id]"
```

However, I am not familiar with that directive so I'm not sure if it accepts a ng-model attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I have created [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/myBRzFOSmpxoC2z4jVMr) that will be referenced throughout the post. The following variables are declared within the scope as follows.

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    'id' : 0,
    'name' : 'Tim'
  },
  {
    'id' : 1,
    'name' : 'John'
  }
];
$scope.ratings = [ '5 stars', '2 stars' ];
```

When you are setting your model to `'catRatings' + {{ cats.id }}` that means somewhere you are declaring a `$scope.catRatings1`, `$scope.catRatings2`, etc. Instead you should bind directly the the category object as follows.

```
<label ng-repeat="person in data">
  <input type="text" ng-model="person.name">
  ...
</label>
```

or bind to an array with a corresponding index

```
<label ng-repeat="person in data">
  ...
  <input type="text" ng-model="ratings[$index]">
</label>
```

or bind to an array using the id...

```
<label ng-repeat="person in data">
  ...
  <input type="text" ng-model="ratings[person.id]">
</label>
```