# Concatenation possible in ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

Just a simple question is it possible to concatenate a string called "id" inside the ng-model to variable product.id in angularjs? Is there a way a approach like this could actually work?

**This works:**

```
ng-model="currentQuantity['id1']"
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
ng-model='currentQuantity[id + "" + product.id]'
```

Comment: don't think you can do that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245842/how-can-i-concatinate-a-ng-model-value-with-a-value-from-a-ng-repeat for some options to do this

Comment: you can create a function getQuantity(product)

Comment: @Claies wish i could show something but the part this small code snippet covers is too big to demonstrate i'm afraid. I will need to reconsider some things as i'm sure the current approach just doesn't fit. All the current given information is very useful.

Comment: don't see why it wouldn't work...concept works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/KhADRd0T3LLDJ6Z5dTMj?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote the string `id` or it will be evaluated as a scope variable

Change:

```
ng-model='currentQuantity[id + "" + product.id]'
```

to

```
ng-model='currentQuantity["id" + product.id]'
```

Comment: Tried this directly after i saw your plunker file. This will save me from a lot of trouble thanks, works like a charm :)

Comment: I would disregard the comments above... concept seems fine to me

Answer (score 5):

One possible workaround would be to use a two dimensional variable to represent your `ng-model`, i.e.

```
ng-model='currentQuantity[id][product.id]'
```